# Why my alertbox is not centered?

Tags: beamer, posters, overleaf

I am using an [Overleaf Poster template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/portrait-beamer-poster-template-jacobs-style/fxfzyznxpghw#.W1MVi9Izrcd) to create a poster. I have four columns and I want an alertbox that takes over the four columns. I can't figure out why the space on the right of the alertbox is bigger than the one on the left. I tried `\centering` before the alert box and `\begin{center}` and neither works. Checking spacing and margins in the beamerthemeconfposter.sty that the template is based I still haven't manage to figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g.  (1-(3+1)*0.024)/3= 0.301
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464  
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708
% Set fourcolwid to be (4*onecolwid)+3*sepwid = 0.88 + 0.072= 
\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\newlength{\fourcolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in} % A0 width: 46.8in
\setlength{\paperheight}{46.8in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\fourcolwid}{0.952\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{The origin and nature of individual differences in the form of Pavlovian conditioned responding} % Poster title

\author{Adela F.} % Author(s)

\institute{X University} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of four major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\fourcolwid} % The first column

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, nunc tellus pulvinar tortor, commodo eleifend risus arcu sed odio:

Mollis dignissim, magna augue tincidunt dolor, interdum vestibulum urna
Sed aliquet luctus lectus, eget aliquet leo ullamcorper consequat. Vivamus eros sem, iaculis ut euismod non, sollicitudin vel orci.
Nascetur ridiculus mus.  


\end{alertblock}


\end{column}

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alert block and title are not centred because manually messing with the paper size is a bad idea - use the options provides by the `beamerposter` package if you want to change the paper format.

And contrary to the comments in your code which say otherwise, the `graphicx` is not required with beamer, as beamer already loads it for for you.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24,size=a0,orientation=portrait]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=ngreen,bg=white} % Colors of the block titles
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=white} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted title}{fg=white,bg=dblue!70} % Colors of the highlighted block titles
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=black,bg=dblue!10}
% Define the column widths and overall poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% In this template, the separation width chosen is 0.024 of the paper width and a 4-column layout
% onecolwid should therefore be (1-(# of columns+1)*sepwid)/# of columns e.g.  (1-(3+1)*0.024)/3= 0.301
% Set twocolwid to be (2*onecolwid)+sepwid = 0.464  
% Set threecolwid to be (3*onecolwid)+2*sepwid = 0.708
% Set fourcolwid to be (4*onecolwid)+3*sepwid = 0.88 + 0.072= 
\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\newlength{\fourcolwid}
%\setlength{\paperwidth}{33.1in} % A0 width: 46.8in
%\setlength{\paperheight}{46.8in} % A0 height: 33.1in
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth} % Width of two columns
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth} % Width of three columns
\setlength{\fourcolwid}{0.952\paperwidth} % Width of four columns
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in} % Reduce the top margin size
%-----------------------------------------------------------

%\usepackage{graphicx}  % Required for including images

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title{The origin and nature of individual differences in the form of Pavlovian conditioned responding} % Poster title

\author{Adela F.} % Author(s)

\institute{X University} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations

\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame

\begin{columns}[t] % The whole poster consists of four major columns, the second of which is split into two columns twice - the [t] option aligns each column's content to the top

%\begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column} % Empty spacer column

\begin{column}{\fourcolwid} % The first column

\begin{alertblock}{Objectives}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur, nunc tellus pulvinar tortor, commodo eleifend risus arcu sed odio:

Mollis dignissim, magna augue tincidunt dolor, interdum vestibulum urna
Sed aliquet luctus lectus, eget aliquet leo ullamcorper consequat. Vivamus eros sem, iaculis ut euismod non, sollicitudin vel orci.
Nascetur ridiculus mus.  


\end{alertblock}


\end{column}

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply @samcarter. I am not sure why, but my poster is not in a portrait orientation if I do not set manually the parameters. I am using sharelatex to do it.

Comment: @AdelaIliescu Can you please run the code from my answer and post the .log file? I'd like to compare it with mine.

Comment: How should I post the log file @samcarter . The text is too long. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: @AdelaIliescu you could use some site similar to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Then you just need to provide the link you obtain.

Comment: @samcarter this is the.log file. [https://pastebin.com/WC1ZXTNy]

Comment: @AdelaIliescu Unfortunately I just get `This page has been removed!` for your pastebin link

Comment: @samcarter i am not sure why. I placed it again https://pastebin.com/qDmzQikG. Lets see if this works... If you follow the link it doesn't work but copy and paste of the link works for me. I made it public, I am not sure why is not working. Clearly I don't know how to share it...

Comment: @AdelaIliescu Thanks. It is working now - I will have a look at it

Comment: @samcarter I have tried your code using Texstudio and it works perfectly. I am assuming the problem is with sharelatex. If you can figure it out I would appreciate it but if not don't worry. Many thanks!

Comment: @AdelaIliescu OK, I compared the log file and found two possible causes: the tex distribution on sharelatex is not up to date and and for `beamerposter.sty` not the file from tex distribution is used, but some local file.

Comment: @samcarter thank you very much for your time and effort. I am happy it works in Texstudio so I will do it there.

Comment: @AdelaIliescu You're welcome!